# Segmentation Fault with `getopt`

Tags: c++, c++11, getopt

I have a function which handles arguments two three global variables.
It works fine with `program -s3`, but if I put a space between the `s` and the argument, I get a segmentation fault even though I'm using `atoi` to remove whitespace.

Here is the code:

```
bool handleArgs(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arg;
    bool rtVal = true;

    while (true)
    {

        static struct option long_options[] =
             {
               {"steps",             optional_argument, 0, 's'},
               {"walks",         optional_argument, 0, 'w'},
               {"dimensions",  optional_argument, 0, 'd'},
               {nullptr, 0, 0, 0}
             };
        int option_index = 0;

        arg = getopt_long (argc, argv, "s::w::d::",long_options, &option_index);
    if(arg == -1)
        {
            break;
        }


        switch(arg)
        {
         case 0:
                     std::cout << long_options[option_index].name  << std::endl;
                     if (optarg)
                         std::cout << " with arg " << optarg << std::endl;
                     break;
            case 's':
                    std::cout << "option -s with value " << atoi(optarg) << std::endl;
                break;
            case 'w':
                    std::cout << "option -w with value " << atoi(optarg) << std::endl;
                break;
            case 'd':
                    std::cout << "option -d with value " << atoi(optarg) << std::endl;
                    break;
            case '?':
                /* getopt_long already printed an error message. */
                rtVal = false;
                break;
            default:
            rtVal = false;
        }
    }
    return rtVal;
}
```

Comment: Where is the declaration for `optarg`?

Comment: @C.R.: in `#include <unistd.h>`, which presumably appears at the top of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your handler for `-s`, you don't check for `optarg` being 0. But you specify two colons after `s` in your option string: (from `man 3 getopt`):

> Two  colons  mean  an option takes an optional arg; if there is text in the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"), then it is returned in optarg, **otherwise `optarg` is set to zero**.  This is a GNU extension.

When the shell starts your program after the invocation `program -s 3`, it provides three elements in the `argv` vector:

```
0: program
1: -s
2: 3
```

Normally, `getopt` would interpret this identically to the invocation `program -s3`, and it's hard to see a reason to change this behaviour. However, gnu helpfully provides you with such an option, allowing you to interpret `program -s 3` as a `-s` option without an argument and a positional argument `3`. Once you go down this road, you must check whether `optarg` is `0` before attempting to use it.

I suspect that you didn't really want to enable this gnu extension. There are very few applications which will benefit from it.

Comment: How would I disable the behaviour? I want `-s3` and `-s 3` to be identical, but the options to still be optional.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. `::` invoked the behaviour, I misread `:` as "mandatory argument" and a `::` as "optional argument".